# Device connecting to root router cannot access other devices connected via WDS bridge router

Tags: windows, wireless-networking, wireless-router, wds

We have a WDS bridge setup for our network, the root router (#1) is a TP-Link TD-W9980 (Dual-band N with built-in VDSL2 modem) and the extending router (#2) is a TP-Link Archer C7 (WDS is enabled for 5GHz) which has a different SSID. This setup has been working very well for most devices.

Recently we picked up a new USB wireless network adapter (TP-Link Archer T2UH) for one of the PCs because the existing one was acting up (TP-Link WN8200ND). This PC runs Windows 7 and connects to the network of router #1 (better signal strength).

However, upon installing the new one, when connected to router #1 that PC can no longer access or ping any devices connected to router #2. Switching back to the old adapter makes it work again, and testing the new one on my laptop showed the same results.

For example, a PC with a wired connection to router #1 has the IP 192.168.1.101 and is accessible, but my PC has a wired connection to router #2 with IP 192.168.1.103 and is not accessible.

Is the adapter DoA, is it a bad product (due to its use of the notorious MT7610U chipset) or am I missing something?

Comment: IIRC it is set to Home. File and printer sharing is turned on

Comment: Do you get the same results with 40mhz channels and up with the TP-Link Archer T2UH? Is it limited to one band or both?

Comment: Our network is broadcast on only 20MHz bandwidth. The T2UH is only capable of 20MHz anyway

Comment: The manufacturers website seems to contradict your last comment. https://www.tp-link.com/us/products/details/cat-5520_Archer-T2UH.html (under the hardware section) seems to indicate it can do "High throughput" 40mhz wide channels on 802.11n (HT40) & "very high throughput" on the 5.8ghz band with 80mhz wide channels. (VHT80). Although I doubt it's relevant to the question it's worth a shot. It sounds like this adapter may be defective honestly.

Answer (score 0):

It may be that the IP address of a device connected to the root router (#1) conflicts with the extending router (#2) IP address. It is recommended to reconfigure the WDS bridge router.

How to configure WDS bridge router we can refer to the following article:

[How to Configure WDS Bridging on TP-Link Dual Band Routers (green UI)?](https://www.tp-link.com/us/faq-440.html)

Comment: I'm not sure how you came to that conclusion. If the routers were mis- configured this would be happening on all devices connecting...

Comment: Whether other devices connected to the root router can access other devices connected via WDS bridge router？

Comment: The op states "Switching back to the old adapter makes it work again". Which would Indicate that this problem is isolated to the (TP-Link Archer T2UH) adapter, and not a router configuration issue.

Comment: Not relevant: The extending router has an IP of 192.168.1.2 which is outside the DHCP range of 192.168.1.100-199.
Also, the extending router has DHCP turned off as per the WDS setup requirements.

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR: Not sure what's going on here but it's fixed

There was another PC that had a T2UH but of an older hardware revision (V1.0). This PC runs Windows 10, and did not have the issue! I tried the new one (V2.0) and it worked as well.

I then took the older one (V1.0) and tried it with the original PC and it worked fine! So I have no idea what was going on, but at least it's fixed...